# Problem in Save Method

Tags: apex

```
public class temp{
public list<CnP_Transaction__c> transactions{get;set;}
public CheckContactController chk{get;set;}
puublic temp(){
    chk = new CheckContactController();
}
    public void savetemp(){
    list<Temporary_contact__c> selectedval = [select id,First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Email__c,Installment__c,Check_temp__c,Map_Contact__c,OrderNumber__c,Recurring__c,Xmldata__c from Temporary_contact__c where Id IN :seltemp] ;    

  // some code here
     insert Transactions; // in transactions say suppose 2 recods are inserted
//In selectedval say suppose 2 Records are coming            
    for(integer i=0; i<selectedval.size(); i++){  
    xmldata = selectedval[i].Xmldata__c;
      oppitems = chk.OpportunityItems(xmldata,transactions,recs,xmlvalue,con.firstname+''+con.lastname);   
    }if(!oppitems.isEmpty()) insert oppitems;
    }
}
```

Now My problem here is for the 1st Record of selectedval I'm getting two transactions in oppitems.But I need to get the first record of selectedval with only 1st Record in transactions and the same way as second record of selectedval with only 2nd Record in transactions.

I can't write
 `oppitems=chk.OpportunityItems(xmldata,transactions,recs,xmlvalue,con.firstname+''+con.lastname);`
outside the for loop as I'm using xmldata in it

If I use `oppitems=chk.OpportunityItems(xmldata,transactions[i],recs,xmlvalue,con.firstname+''+con.lastname);`.It is throwing me an error because transactions should be a list but here transactions[i] is a string

Stucked here.Any help on this pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot change CheckContactController, may be use a temporary list?

```
for(integer i=0; i<selectedval.size(); i++){  
    list<CnP_Transaction__c> tmpTransactions = new List<CnP_Transaction__c>();
    tmpTransactions.add(transactions[i]);
    xmldata = selectedval[i].Xmldata__c;
    oppitems = chk.OpportunityItems(xmldata,tmpTransactions,recs,xmlvalue,con.firstname+''+con.lastname);   
}
if(!oppitems.isEmpty()) insert oppitems;
```